# PHP Regex for this pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Need help with a regular expression.

1) Format:

```
 Advisor Geologist – HighMount Exploration & Production LLC – Oklahoma City, OK
```

I'd like to get the text between the last character and the dash. ie. `Oklahoma City, OK`. Note the text might contain multiple dashes.

Tried this:

```
~-([.*$]+)~
```

Trying to get between the dash and the end of the string (.*$). Need to know how to check for the last occurrence of the dash.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Show us what you've tried, so we have a starting point to work with.

Comment: Have you tried anythig? See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php to get started with regex in PHP.

Comment: Sorry have updated my question

Comment: @m.buettner - You don't know **why** OP asks for regex solution - maybe (s)he needs regex and any non-regex solution is then worthless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use regex, then go with

```
$pattern = '/[^\s–-][^–-]*?(?=\s*$)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

Test this demo **[here](http://ideone.com/JhqGY0)**.

Comment: (in reply to your comment on the question) sure, and I didn't downvote your solution because it used a regex, but because it did not fulfill the specification stated in the question. While I still prefer the the non-regex solution, this one gets my upvote, because (for some odd reason) the OP might actually **need** a regex. And this one is working pretty well ;) (as opposed to the last one)

Comment: @BotondBalázs Ωmega had posted a different solution before, which is the one I was referring to

Comment: Tried this solution but it when I ````var_dump()```` $matches I just get the whole string. The string I passed in was "VP of Exploration - Global Recruiters of Dallas - Houston, TX"

Comment: @iamjonesy that was my fault then. I adjusted the regex to the dash- characters you used in the question (which are not `-` but `–`). Adjusted it again so that it work with both characters. Try again please

Comment: @m.buettner: sorry then, I totally misunderstood it. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a regular expression, [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) the string on the dash, and take the last element.

```
$str = 'Advisor Geologist – HighMount Exploration & Production LLC – Oklahoma City, OK';
$arr = explode( '–', $str);
$last = trim( end( $arr));
echo $last;
```

Much more efficient.

Comment: How you know OP does not need regex? You don't see whole picture of the issue (s)he is working on... Sometimes users need regex, because they use some tool or library that works with regex, not the actual PHP code...

Comment: The whole picture of the issue is depicted in the OP, unless I'm supposed to be a mind reader?

Comment: Your solution is excellent, if OP does not need regex. You should offer a regex alternative as well - that is my point...

Comment: This would be a good solution but please note that those characters in `$str` aren't dashes, they are something else.

Comment: Didn't specifically need a regex. Couldn't think of a solution that wasn't a regex. This has worked great. Wasn't aware of the ````end()```` so Thanks!

Comment: This solution worked great but thought I should mark the other question as the answer as my question was for a regex. (just for others who may come across this)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a regex, this is the simplest one I can think of:

```
'/\s*([^-]+)\s*$/'
```

Let's see how it works:

- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, etc.)
- `([^-]+)` matches one or more characters that are not dashes
- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, etc.)
- `$` matches the end of the string

**Please note that what the `–` character in your post is not a simple dash.** It is some other Unicode character. If you need to match that too, you should update the regex this way:

```
'/\s*([^-–]+)\s*$/'
```

Here is a code sample:

```
preg_match(
    '/\s*([^-]+)\s*$/',
    'Advisor Geologist – HighMount Exploration & Production LLC - Oklahoma City, OK',
    $matches);
$city = $matches[1];
```

Comment: With this pattern you would need to trim spaces then... Also, no need to escape `-` inside of `[...]` if `-` is first, last or only one in...

Answer (score 0):

Also [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) can help.

```
 $str = 'Advisor Geologist – HighMount Exploration & Production LLC – Oklahoma City, OK';
 $result = trim(substr($str, strrpos($str, '-')+1));
```

For fixed formats you can use `list() & explode()`:

```
 $str = 'Advisor Geologist – HighMount Exploration & Production LLC – Oklahoma City, OK';
 list($occupation, $company, $city) = explode('-', $str);
```